# Linux System is crashing while typing List<Map<String, String>> in flutter using VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I am learning flutter. Whenever I am typing

```
List<Map<String,String>>
```

my system gets hanged. I am using VS Code in Linux Mint.
I have tried this 8-10 times, every time I open the code, the code says Analysing and Hangs after 10-15 seconds.

Below is the file which I am modifying.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, String> initialProduct;
  ProductManager({this.initialProduct});
  @override
  _ProductManagerState createState() => _ProductManagerState();
}

class _ProductManagerState extends State<ProductManager> {
  List<Map<String,String>> _products = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Where is the problem, is it in the dart/flutter plugin which I am using in VS Code, or is it in the VS Code itself. Can anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: Can't say what's the problem with your system. I just tried it on Ubuntu, its working perfectly. VSCode with flutter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have been hitting this bug in the analysis server (which the VS Code extension uses for a lot of the language functionality):

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34850

It's been fixed but the fix may not have made the Flutter stable channel yet. Try switching to the Flutter dev channel temporarily and if you still see it there, please file a new issue on GitHub.